# Leer fichero C#

Tags: c#, .net

Se ha de leer un fichero hasta el final, para ello utlizo las funciones de System.IO pero me encuentro con el problema de que la variable no me guarda correctamente los datos. Me gustaría poder resolverlo sin usar EndOfStream.

```
using System;
using System.IO; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using File_Functions;


namespace _01FICHEROS {
class Program {
    public static String input = "inputfile.txt";
    public static String output = "outputfile.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args) {



        Console.Write(Functions.ReadFile(input));
        Functions.End();
    }
    }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace File_Functions {
     class Functions {
    public static StreamReader sr = null;
    public static StreamWriter sw = null;

    public static String ReadFile(String path) {
        String lines = "";
        try {
            sr = new StreamReader(path);
            while ((lines = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                lines += sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        return (lines);

    }

    public static void End() {

        Console.Write("\n\nPULSAR CUALQUIER TECLA PARA FINALIZAR...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Que variable no guarda que datos correctamente? cual es el problema?

Comment: La variable line, debería imprimirme todas las líneas en cambio no lo hace

Comment: Tu while esta mal.. ahora te escribo una respuesta corta

Comment: Hola, @nauumb, @gbianchi  por qué no usar el método `File.ReadAllLines` ? Este método abre el archivo, lo lee entero,  devuelve un array de cadenas y luego cierra el archivo. Ejemplo de uso: `string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);`

Comment: Inclusive se puede usar `File.ReadAllText`,que abre un archivo de texto, lee todo el texto del archivo en una cadena y, a continuación, cierra el archivo. Ejemplo de uso: `string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);`

Answer (score 4):

Cuando haces

```
lines = sr.ReadLine()
```

Lo que estas haciendo, es diciendole que tu variable `lines` es igual a lo que devuelve `sr.ReadLine()`.

Como lo haces en el `while`, cuando llega a la ultima linea, `lines` queda en `null`, y es cuando sale. En cada linea estas cambiando el valor de `lines` a la ultima linea leida, y para colmo dentro del `while`, sumandole el contenido de la linea siguiente. Menos mal que tus lineas son pares, si fueran impares daria error este codigo.

No se porque no queres usar EndOfStream, pero es el camino a seguir. Si no, vas a tener que plantear tu lógica de otra forma totalmente distinta.

Como nota, para leer archivos de texto, mejor usar un TextReader.

Comment: Intentaba no usar EndOfStream para tener otra opción de hacerlo, muchas gracias por la respuesta. En cuanto a losTextReader aún no sé usarlos, todo esto es con motivo académico

Comment: @nauumb si es acadamico, nada mejor que aprender a usarlos, salvo que te lo prohiban. Los dos heredan del mismo tipo de objeto (reader) y hacen basicamente lo mismo. Es mas, un StreamReader, hereda de un TextReader

Comment: Entonces, la diferencia principal cúal es, porque no me queda nada clara con la documentación que he encontrado

Comment: que documentacion miraste? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: exactamente esa, con ella no consigo ver claramente las principales diferencias entre estos métodos

Comment: No son metodos, son clases, y se preocupan por diferentes cosas. Un textreader lee texto de un archivo de texto. Un streamreader espera bytes codificados de alguna forma (cada caracter puede medir mas de un byte). Uno trabaja mas abajo en la memoria que el otro.

Answer (score 0):

para leer un archivo de texto hasta el final bastaría con usar el método [File.ReadAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2). En cuyo caso únicamente tendrías que hacer

```
 String lines = File.ReadAllText(path);
```